# function defined by its derivative at a specific point

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I was solving a physics problem about a falling element that gets air resistance.
In that case, the acceleration, which is the derivative of velocity, is defined as
$$a=\frac{mg-bv}{m}$$
And, m,g,b is all a constant.
Let's define a function $v(t)=\text{the velocity at the time t}$
Then, we can define the derivative of velocity($a$) with the expression written above.
Like this.
$$\frac{dv(t)}{dt}=\frac{mg-bv(t)}{m}$$
Now, we can define the physics problem I was solving by pure math.

**Abstracted problem**
function v(t) is defined as
$$v(t)=\frac{mg-m\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{b}$$
Can v(t) be defined without using it's derivative?
If it can't, why? If it can, how can it be done, and what is the definition?

I am new pretty new to calculus and also physics. This question might be a stupid or a simple question. In that case, sorry. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain why you swapped the positions of $v(t)$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}v(t)}{\mathrm{d}t}$ between the second and third display equations?

Comment: @EricTowers I have no special reason of that. Just wanted to define the function by the derivative.

Comment: @EricTowers It appears OP solved for $v(t)$ in the third display (note the denominator also changed).

Comment: @Teepeemm : Ah.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$a=\frac{mg-bv}{m} \iff a=g-\frac b mv$$

and by $u=g-\frac b mv$
$$\frac m b \dot u=\frac m b (0-\frac b m u)=-u \implies \frac m b \frac{du}{dt}=-u \implies \frac m b \frac{du}{u}=-dt$$$$\implies \frac m b \ln u=-t +C' \implies u=e^{-\frac b mt+C'}=Ce^{-\frac b mt}$$

that is

$$g-\frac b mv=Ce^{-\frac b mt}$$

$$v=\frac m b g-\frac m bCe^{-\frac b mt}$$

and by $v(0)=v_0$ we  obtain $C=g-\frac b m v_0$.

Comment: Doesn't it has to be $v=\frac m b g-\frac m bCe^{\frac{-b}{m}t}$...?

Comment: @dissolve Yes of course! I forgot a minus sign in the first step! I fix that.

Comment: @dissolve The physical interpretation helps a lot in this case! Good catch! Bye

Comment: Also, I cannot understand the reason why $\frac m b \dot u=-u$.
Could you explain it?

Comment: @dissolve We have defined $$u=g-\frac b mv \implies u'=0-\frac b m v'=-\frac b m a \implies a=- \frac m b u'$$ and the equation becomes $$\frac m b u'=-u$$

Comment: Understood. Thanks.
Can you also explain why $\frac{du}{u}=-dt$ implies $\frac m b \ln u=-t +C'$

Comment: @dissolve This a tecnique to solve differential equation by "separation of variables". In that step we are integrating both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can solved. What you have is a differential equation and the standard techniques for solving them give you that$$v(t)=\frac{gm}b-Ke^{-bt/m},$$for some constant $K$. Of course, $K=\frac{gm}b-v(0)$.